# SQL Query to retrieve month name from database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've following query, what i want to do is, i just want month name from the date column, in the following query its displaying month number

```
SELECT MONTH(Invoice_Date), SUM(R.Total) AS TOTAL
FROM Sales R
GROUP BY MONTH(Invoice_Date)
ORDER BY MONTH(Invoice_Date);
```

I tried MonthName function, also i tried convert function but neither one is working.
Following error is displayed Undefined Function.
Please Help, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, Invoice_Date), SUM(R.Total) AS TOTAL
FROM Sales R
GROUP BY DATENAME(month, Invoice_Date)
ORDER BY DATENAME(month, Invoice_Date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try datepart function of MS SQL 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

MS sql query will be:

```
SELECT 
  DATEPART(month,Invoice_Date), 
  SUM(R.Total) AS TOTAL 
FROM Sales R 
GROUP BY DATEPART(month,Invoice_Date) 
ORDER BY DATEPART(month,Invoice_Date)
```

Assuming that Invoice_Date "Is an expression that can be resolved to a time, date, smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2, or datetimeoffset value. date can be an expression, column expression, user-defined variable, or string literal."

Comment: The `DATEPART` function isn't available in Access as it is an T-SQL function, and also it returns and int and not the name of the month.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use MS Access only and not SQL Server and therefore can't use T-SQL functions one way to do this is to use the `switch` function like this:

```
SELECT SWITCH( 
  MONTH(invoice_date) = 1, "January", 
  MONTH(invoice_date) = 2, "February", 
  MONTH(invoice_date) = 3, "March"
  MONTH(invoice_date) = 4, "April"
  MONTH(invoice_date) = 5, "May"
  MONTH(invoice_date) = 6, "June"
  MONTH(invoice_date) = 7, "July"
  MONTH(invoice_date) = 8, "August"
  MONTH(invoice_date) = 9, "September"
  MONTH(invoice_date) = 10, "October"
  MONTH(invoice_date) = 11, "November"
  MONTH(invoice_date) = 12, "December"
) AS MonthName, SUM(R.Total) AS TOTAL

FROM Sales R
GROUP BY MONTH(Invoice_Date)
ORDER BY MONTH(Invoice_Date);
```

Another option would be to create a table containing month names and number and retrieve the name from that via a join.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using T-SQL it is possible to get the month name from month number of a date.

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, MONTH(Invoice_Date), 0 ) -1);
```

Then, your final query will look like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(Invoice_Date), DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, MONTH(Invoice_Date), 0 ) -1) as MonthName, SUM(R.Total) AS TOTAL
FROM Sales R
GROUP BY MONTH(Invoice_Date)
ORDER BY MONTH(Invoice_Date);
```